# Javascript local and global variables losing scope in callback function

Tags: javascript

I have tried different variable scopes and none seem to work? My callback is getting a valid result but no matter the scope of the variable I assign it to I lose the value once the callback ends??

```
var geocoder;
var Lat;
var Long;

function codeAddress()
{


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var addy1......

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': fullAddress }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            Long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }


    });
    alert(Lat);
    document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").type.value = Lat;
    document.getElementById("Address_AddyLong").value = Long;
}
```

Thank for your input.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: They're not losing scope, they simple were not assigned a value when you accessed them. `geocode` is an **asynchronous** function, and you will need to put everything that works with its result in the callback

Comment: Well I tried that originally....and switched to this. I can try again.   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                document.getElementById("Address_AddyLong").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            } doesn't update the form???

Answer (score 1):

`geocode` is an asynchronous function, so when you call it, it immediately returns and the next lines are executed before the value of `Lat` is set. Think of it this way:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': fullAddress }, /*...*/); // 1
alert(Lat); // 2
document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").type.value = Lat; // 3
document.getElementById("Address_AddyLong").value = Long; // 4
```

What you want to do is to actually read the value of `Lat` in the callback itself:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': fullAddress }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        Long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        alert(Lat);
        document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").type.value = Lat;
        document.getElementById("Address_AddyLong").value = Long;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }


});
```

Comment: Whoever down voted could rub my nose with a correct answer. Ameen it does NOT work. alert(Lat) has proper value but the document elements do not update??

Comment: Well, what's the type of `Address_AddyLat`? Is it an `input` with type `text`? If so, you want to do `document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").value = Lat` (without the type)

Answer (score 0):

I think Ameen has the right of it. Your element reference must be incorrect.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").value = Lat;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").setAttribute("value",Lat);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ameen said geocode is a asynch process so you need to put your alert & display code in callback function. and your another mistake is that you are using lat() & lng() as a method, its not a method its a property you just need to use it directly. so your code some look like.

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': fullAddress }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        Long = results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        alert(Lat);
        document.getElementById("Address_AddyLat").value = Lat;
        document.getElementById("Address_AddyLong").value = Long;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
```